# Persisting user selected data in Django application

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django application were a user can have multiple accounts. All the functionality in the app should be associated with the currently selected account. For instance, if the user want's to modify an account's preferences, when they click on preferences, the app should pull up the preferences for the account they are working with.

Initially, I tried using the session to set the current account but was unable to get that to work. After further reading, that seemed like a poor choice. What I'm doing now is passing the account_id (aid) as a URL variable to each view, and passing that to the template.

urls.py

```
    url(r"^(?P<aid>\d+)/categories/$", views.manage_categories),
    url(r"^(?P<aid>\d+)/preferences/$", views.manage_preferences),
    url(r"^(?P<aid>\d+)/transactions/$", views.manage_transactions),
    url(r"^(?P<aid>\d+)/transactions/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", views.edit_transaction),
```

views.py

```
    def manage_categories(request, aid=None):
        ...

    def edit_transaction(request, aid=None, pk=None):
        ...
```

So as they navigate through the app, the selected account is available for each view to use in filtering DB results. It seems like there could be a better way to manage this since it requires passing the account id to every view, and passing it down to every template. I like the idea of using the session to manage it  but was unclear about how to make that work.  Is the solution of using the account id in the URL a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: If the user accounts are managed and authenticated with [Django's authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) there is already a user object in every request, use `request.user`.

Comment: It's not user accounts in this case. The account in this app is a bank account. Each user may have many (bank) accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be solved using user sessions. There's already one built in, see [Django's sessions framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/).

The first steps with Django's default sessions using a database backend:

1. Add `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in your `settings.py`
2. Add `django.contrib.sessions` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`
3. Run `manage.py migrate` to create the database table that stores session data

Now you are able to use sessions in your views. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views):

> When SessionMiddleware is activated, each HttpRequest object – the first argument to any Django view function – will have a session attribute, which is a dictionary-like object.
>
> You can read it and write to request.session at any point in your view. You can edit it multiple times.

I would use a view to select an account and save it to the user's session:

```
request.session['account'] = aid
```

Afterwards you can read this value like this:

```
request.session.get('account', None)
```